# win32: Reading message queue

Tags: c, winapi, message-queue

I need to read the thread message queue, but I cannot use the traditional `GetMessage`-in-a-loop approach since this thread already handles other data sources via `WaitForMultipleObjects`. Is there a way to add the thread message queue as an additional event source for `WaitForMultipleObjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) or [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684245.aspx).